# vim snipmate shortcut for inserting snip inside tab

Tags: vim, snipmate

I have been using Vim with the [snipMate plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) for creating HTML code.
This is the code I want to type quickly:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="this.html">that</a></li>
</ul>
```

So I start in insert mode typing `ul`<kbd>Tab</kbd>`li`<kbd>Tab</kbd> but then when I try typing `a`<kbd>tab</kbd> to create the link snippet it doesn't work, it moves to the end of the line (which is what the snippet says to do).

I have tried to escape the snip by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, but once I enter insert mode <kbd>Tab</kbd> still takes me to the end of the line. Currently the best way I can get it to work is by accepting the <kbd>Tab</kbd> to the end of the line, moving backwards then insert. Is this method the most efficient way of doing this? How do you escape a snippet?

I also have the following snippet for `a` in `html.snippets`

```
snippet a
    <a href="${1:#}">${2:$1}</a>${3}
```

Pressing `a`<kbd>Tab</kbd> puts me after the `href="` and I type `this.html`, the snippet puts `this.html` before the `</a>`. When I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and then want to type over the second `this.html` (like in TextMate) and so I type `that`, but it leaves `thathis.html`?

Answer (score 2):

Snipmate does not support nested snippets. I suggest you try [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715).

Answer (score 1):

I think you might just be after:

```
snippet a
    <a href="${1:#}">${2}</a>${3}
```

Also, if the cursor moving to the end of the line is annoying, drop `${3}`, or if you wanted to edit the tag content in hindsight (after moving to the end of the line), use <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> (*change inner tag*)